# For a triangle $ABC$, let $2 \sin(A) = 3 \tan(B)$, and $\frac{2\cos(C)}{3 \cos(B)} = \frac{2 \cos(A)}{3} + \sin^{2}(C) + \cos^2(C) - \sec^2(B)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A student I am tutoring presented a bonus question from one of their practice midterms that has me quite stumped as its quite a leap in difficulty, and I haven't worked with identities in quite a few years now.

The question is as follows: For a triangle $ABC$, let $2 \sin(A) = 3 \tan(B)$, and $\frac{2\cos(C)}{3} = \frac{2 \cos(A)}{3} + \sin^{2}(C) + \cos^2(C) - \sec^2B$. The task is to solve for angle $B$.

This is the work I have so far - we have that: $\tan(B) = (2/3) \sin(A)$, of which subsituting $\sec^2(x) = \tan^2 x + 1$ in the second equation yields

$\frac{2\cos(C)}{3 \cos(B)} = \frac{2 \cos(A)}{3} + \sin^{2}(C) + \cos^2(C) - \sec^2B=\frac{2 \cos(A)}{3} - \tan^2 (B)$

It's at this point I'm completely stuck, every possible expression that I attempt blows up and gets further from the equation. My intuition is telling me that we probably want to get an expression on one variable, express as trigonometric ratios and solve in terms of that, but any clues or suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: Fixed the question! Going to take another crack at it.

Edit2: Using Mike's answer, I was able to work out the following:

$2\sin(A)\tan(B) - 2\cos(A) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(A) - \tan^2 (B)$
$= 3\tan^2 (B) - 2\cos(A) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(A) - \tan^2 (B)$
$\implies  \tan^2 (B) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(A)$.

From here, I used the $2 \sin(A) = 3 \tan(B) \implies 4\sin^{2}(A) = 9 \tan^2 (B)$ which yields $4\sin^2(A) = 6 \cos(A) \implies  -4\cos^2(A) - \cos(A) + 4 = 0$

Factoring this expression yields equation $(2\cos(A) - 1)(-2\cos(A) -4)=0$ which has solutions $\cos(A) = \frac{1}{2}, -2$. As $\cos(A) \in [-1,1]$, it must be the case $\cos(A) = \frac{1}{2}$

Next, substitute this into the above expression $\tan^@(B) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(A)$, we get:

$\frac{1}{3} = \tan^2 B \implies \tan(B) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so $B = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Thank you again, Mike.

Comment: First thing: you messed up a sign in your simplification.  Secondly, have you found some way to use that ABC is a triangle?

Comment: @Mike Thank you for pointing out my mistake. On using $ABC$ as a triangle, I arrived one expression makes use of $A+B+C = \pi$, but the expressions ultimately blew up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'll take a crack at this.  Since we have some relationship between trigonometric functions of A and B, let's try replacing C and see if we can eliminate A or B down the line.  Where you last left off, there was a term involving $\cos (C)$, so we have

$$\cos(C)=\cos[\pi-(A+B)]=-\cos(A+B)=\sin(A)\sin(B)-\cos(A)\cos(B)$$

Plugging this in gives

$$\dfrac{2\sin(A)\sin(B)-2\cos(A)\cos(B)}{3\cos(B)}=\dfrac{2\cos(A)}{3\cos(B)}-\tan^2(B)$$

Splitting up the fraction, we get

$$\frac23\sin(A)\tan(B)-\frac23\cos(A)=\dfrac{2\cos(A)}{3\cos(B)}-\tan^2(B)$$

The $\tan(B)$'s are easily replaced.  The $\cos(B)$ is tougher but can be done.  Have you double-checked that the problem was copied correctly?

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you again for replying. You are correct, the question was not copied correctly. I have updated the expression above to reflect this mistake. I will update when I have made progress.